# python module importing difficulties

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, importerror

Im relatively new to python so forgive me if this is fundamental.

I have a directory where I have my main applicatino code , in a file `app.py` . I then have a sub directory Model which contains the required `__init__.py` file, and `backend.py`

in `app.py` when I try to `import model.backend` I get an `ImportError: no module named model.backend`

However if in the same directory that `app.py` lives I drop into a python shell and type `import model.backend` it works. Why? Why can I import it in the shell but not in my application?

Edit:
My directory structure looks like

```
src/
`- myapp
   +- __init__.py
   +- app.py
   `- model/
      +- __init__.py
      `- backend.py
```

Thanks

Comment: add library path: `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("model"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have this structure?

```
src/
`- myapp
   +- __init__.py
   +- app.py
   `- model/
      +- __init__.py
      `- backend.py
```

in particular, check that there are `__init__.py` in both places.

if so, then `PYTHONPATH=..../src` (replace `....` with the correct path) and

```
from myapp.model import backend
```

should work correctly.

the reason your interactive shell works is that the current directory is automatically added to PYTHONPATH.

[edit: changed `Model` to `model`]

you are making a mistake somewhere.  check everything again.  what i described above works (the pyc files are generated by python - ignore them):

```
> tree myapp/
myapp/
├── app.py
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
└── model
    ├── backend.py
    ├── backend.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __init__.pyc

1 directory, 7 files
> cat myapp/app.py

from myapp.model import backend

> cat myapp/model/backend.py

print "importing backend"

> PYTHONPATH=. python -m myapp.app
importing backend
> python -m myapp.app
importing backend
```

(you don't even need PYTHONPATH above since you're already running at exactly the right level).

Comment: I do have the appropriate code structure. I tried adding my source path to PYTHONPATH but I'm still receiving the same error. My pythonpath had nothing in it before.

Comment: I originally had it as myapp.model, and that didnt work. I just changed it to import model and that works. But now I've lost the concept of a package. Why does model work but myapp.model doesnt?

Comment: i've worked through the entire example above.  copy that exactly.  it works.  you must be making a mistake...

Answer (score 1):

In `myapp/__init__.py` you can add:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '.')
```